# css li content displays wrong characters in UTF-8

Tags: css

I am trying to create style to display arrow on place of li element.

```
$("html > head").append("<style id=styles>div#panel { position: absolute; border-radius: 3px; font-family:'Arial Black'; font-size:13px; }\n\r" +
     "ul li:before { content: \"\00BB \8680\"; }"
    + "</style>\n\r");
```

What I see are some mishmash characters but not arrow. The page charset is utf-8.

I read this:
http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/
http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

How to fix it?

Comment: use html special char - \00BB = &raquo; \8680 = &#8680;

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find complete list? Or is there some online conversion tool? From hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Replace `content: \"\00BB` with `content: '\\00BB'`.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("html > head").append("<style>div#panel{ position: absolute; border-radius: 3px; font-family:'Arial Black'; font-size:13px; } ul { list-style: none; } ul li:before{ content: '\\00BB'; margin-right: 10px; } </style>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```